# Is there a C++ library that wraps a internal type to be able to derive from that internal type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, integer-arithmetic, representation

I have this template that wrap an unsigned integer type (any) :

```
    template<std::unsigned_integral T>
    struct base_dig_t 
    {T m_data;};
```

Then I have this template to modify the behavior of the arithmetic operators etc. :

```
    template<std::unsigned_integral T,apropied_number_concept<T> R>
    struct dig_t : 
           public base_dig_t<T> 
    {};
```

that it does not contain any more data member: only the modifications on the arithmetic operators.

> **BEGIN : CONTEXT**

What I want to achieve:

> I want hold in a *Container* with order **base_dig_t<T>** objects
> from the derived **dig_t<T,R>** objects. The *Container* would hold
> the **R template non-type argument** for the correct function.  The
> *Container* for **dig_t<T,R>**, would represent a number with   some format, length and radix **R**. For example (supose that we have an
> enumerated type EF with the formats):

```
template<typename T, T R,EF f, std::size_t length>
struct number_t : 
    public std::array<base_dig_t<T>,length>
{
    // It works with dig_t<T,R>
    // The behavior of this container vary with `f`
};
```

> **END   : CONTEXT**

But I think that this code have to exits out there. Is it true?

Comment: Maybe elaborate on "what you want to achieve" in details to provide more context to your question.